# Spring security - maximumSessions() - not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-security, spring-session

I have a project in Spring boot, with Spring security and spring session. I wanted to persist my session in a database so I specified it in application.properties:

```java
spring.session.store-type=jdbc
```

I also wanted to login into my app via REST API (because I use React to create pages).
This is how I've done it:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
public class UserController {

    private final UserService userService;
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry<? extends Session>  sessionRegistry;
    private final SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry<? extends Session> sessionRegistry,
                          SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.sessionRegistry = sessionRegistry;
        this.securityContextRepository = securityContextRepository;
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(@RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        loginRequest.getEmail(),
                        loginRequest.getPassword()
                )
        );

        SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        securityContext.setAuthentication(authentication);
        securityContextRepository.saveContext(securityContext, request, response);
        sessionRegistry.registerNewSession(request.getSession().getId(), authentication.getPrincipal());

        return ResponseEntity.ok("User authenticated successfully");
    }
```

When I make this POST request with valid credentials everything works as desired. I can see a record in the database (spring_session - table) with principal_name (column) corresponding to the just authenticated user.

Following spring docs I found out maximumSessions() method. I used it in my code (to value 1), however it doesn't work. I can login on one browser, and then once again on another browser.
This is my SecurityConfig:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    private final UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    private final CustomOAuth2UserService customOAuth2UserService;
    private final JdbcIndexedSessionRepository jdbcIndexedSessionRepository;

    public SecurityConfig(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder,
                          CustomOAuth2UserService customOAuth2UserService, JdbcIndexedSessionRepository jdbcIndexedSessionRepository) {
        this.userDetailsServiceImpl = userDetailsServiceImpl;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
        this.customOAuth2UserService = customOAuth2UserService;
        this.jdbcIndexedSessionRepository = jdbcIndexedSessionRepository;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/api/users/login").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/users/register").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/users/current/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/users").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .requestMatchers("/api/tasks").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .sessionManagement((sessionManagement) -> sessionManagement
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
                        .maximumSessions(1)
                        .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
                        .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry())
                )
                .securityContext((securityContext) -> securityContext
                        .securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository())
                )
                .anonymous(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .logout((logout) -> logout
                        .logoutUrl("/api/users/logout")
                        .logoutSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) -> response.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value()))
                        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                        .clearAuthentication(true)
                        .deleteCookies("SESSION")
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .requestCache((cache) -> cache.requestCache(new NullRequestCache()))
                .cors((cors) -> cors
                        .configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
                )
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository() {
        return new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository();
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry<? extends Session> sessionRegistry() {
        return new SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry<>(jdbcIndexedSessionRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsServiceImpl);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);

        ProviderManager providerManager = new ProviderManager(authenticationProvider);
        providerManager.setEraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication(false);

        return providerManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:3000"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST", "PUT", "DELETE"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

}
```

I would assume that my configuration is not quite good.

I've been looking through similar problems on the Internet but nothing helped.
I have overrided equals() and hashCode() methods in my User model and in UserDetails. I have tested it. Users are equals if emails are the same. Hashcode is generated using email field.

I would assume, that something wrong is in my login endpoint. Maybe sesionRegistry somehow does not communicate well with securityContextRepository.
I have tried following spring security docs, but encountered some problems and the above code is what I came up with.

**-----UPDATE_1-----**

I've just discovered that the root of my problems lies in securityConfig precisely in SecurityFilterChain. The configuration stored there is not enough to automatically do things like maximumSessions(1).
In the Controller I manually serve the AuthenticationManager while it should be declared in the SecurityFilterChain like:

```
.authenticationManager(authenticationManager())
```

It still does not resolve my problem but I believe this is a small step forward

**-----UPDATE_2-----**

With the help from @m-deinum the working code states as below:

```java
//...
public class SecurityConfig{
private final UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    private final CustomOAuth2UserService customOAuth2UserService;
    private final JdbcIndexedSessionRepository jdbcIndexedSessionRepository;
    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public SecurityConfig(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder,
                          CustomOAuth2UserService customOAuth2UserService, JdbcIndexedSessionRepository jdbcIndexedSessionRepository, ObjectMapper mapper) {
        this.userDetailsServiceImpl = userDetailsServiceImpl;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
        this.customOAuth2UserService = customOAuth2UserService;
        this.jdbcIndexedSessionRepository = jdbcIndexedSessionRepository;
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .addFilterBefore(loginFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/api/users/login").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/users/register").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/users/current/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/oauth2/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/users").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .requestMatchers("/api/tasks").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .sessionManagement((sessionManagement) -> sessionManagement
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
                )
                .securityContext((securityContext) -> securityContext
                        .securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository())
                )
                .anonymous(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .requestCache((cache) -> cache.requestCache(new NullRequestCache()))
                .logout((logout) -> logout
                        .logoutUrl("/api/users/logout")
                        .logoutSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) -> response.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value()))
                        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                        .clearAuthentication(true)
                        .deleteCookies("SESSION")
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .cors((cors) -> cors
                        .configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
                )
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);

        return http.build();
    }

 ///previous beans...

    @Bean
    public LoginFilter loginFilter() {
        return new LoginFilter(mapper, authenticationManager(), securityContextRepository(), sessionAuthenticationStrategy());
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy sessionControlAuthenticationStrategy = new ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy(sessionRegistry());
        sessionControlAuthenticationStrategy.setMaximumSessions(1);
sessionControlAuthenticationStrategy.setExceptionIfMaximumExceeded(false);
        return sessionControlAuthenticationStrategy;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<LoginFilter> loginFilterRegistration() {
        FilterRegistrationBean<LoginFilter> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<LoginFilter>(loginFilter());
        registration.setEnabled(false);
        return registration;
    }
}
```

And LoginFilter class:

```java
public class LoginFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public LoginFilter(ObjectMapper mapper, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository,
                       SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy) {
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/users/login", "POST"));
        this.mapper = mapper;
        setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        setSecurityContextRepository(securityContextRepository);
        setSessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        LoginRequest loginRequest = mapper.readValue(request.getInputStream(), LoginRequest.class);
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.unauthenticated(loginRequest.getEmail(),
                loginRequest.getPassword());
        // Allow subclasses to set the "details" property
        setDetails(request, authRequest);

        return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
    }

    protected void setDetails(HttpServletRequest request, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest) {
        authRequest.setDetails(this.authenticationDetailsSource.buildDetails(request));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your controller lacks integration. THe regular spring security login materials fire events when a login succeeds (yours doesn't). It also interferes with the filter chain as you register sessions yourself instead of letting Spring Security handle it. Instead of re-inventing Spring Security login I would suggest you write a filter, which would extend the `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` and implements the request abstract methods. This will then properly integrate with Spring Security and its features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ditch your controller and move your logic to a filter instead and let that filter extend the `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`. This will then properly integrate with the Spring Security infrastructure. Unless you want to do everything manually ofcourse.

```java
@Component
public class LoginFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

  private final ObjectMapper mapper;

  public LoginFilter(ObjectMapper mapper) {
    super(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/users/login", "POST");
    this.mapper = mapper;
  }

  public abstract Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
     LoginRequest loginRequest = mapper.readValue(request.getInputStream(), LoginRequest.class);
     UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.unauthenticated(loginRequest.getEmail(),
                loginRequest.getPassword());
        // Allow subclasses to set the "details" property
        setDetails(request, authRequest);

     return authenticationManager.authenticate(authRequest);                
  } 

 protected void setDetails(HttpServletRequest request, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest) {
authRequest.setDetails(this.authenticationDetailsSource.buildDetails(request));
 }
}
```

Something like that. Now we need to add this to the security filter chain.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final CustomOAuth2UserService customOAuth2UserService;
    private final JdbcIndexedSessionRepository jdbcIndexedSessionRepository;
    private final LoginFilter loginFilter;

    public SecurityConfig(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,
                          CustomOAuth2UserService customOAuth2UserService, JdbcIndexedSessionRepository jdbcIndexedSessionRepository, LoginFilter loginFilter) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.customOAuth2UserService = customOAuth2UserService;
        this.jdbcIndexedSessionRepository = jdbcIndexedSessionRepository;
        this.loginFilter = loginFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                addFilterBefore(loginFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/api/users/login").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/users/register").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/users/current/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/users").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .requestMatchers("/api/tasks").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .sessionManagement((sessionManagement) -> sessionManagement
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
                        .maximumSessions(1)
                        .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
                        .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry())
                )
                .securityContext((securityContext) -> securityContext
                        .securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository())
                )
                .anonymous(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .logout((logout) -> logout
                        .logoutUrl("/api/users/logout")
                        .logoutSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) -> response.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value()))
                        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                        .clearAuthentication(true)
                        .deleteCookies("SESSION")
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .requestCache((cache) -> cache.requestCache(new NullRequestCache()))
                .cors((cors) -> cors
                        .configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
                )
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository() {
        return new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository();
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry<? extends Session> sessionRegistry() {
        return new SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry<>(jdbcIndexedSessionRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);

        ProviderManager providerManager = new ProviderManager(authenticationProvider);
        providerManager.setEraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication(false);
        return providerManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:3000"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST", "PUT", "DELETE"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    // Needed to prevent Spring Boot from automatically registering this filter in the regular filter chain. 
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<LoginFilter> loginFilterRegistration(LoginFilter loginFilter) {
      FilterRegistrationBean<LoginFilter> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<LoginFilter>(loginFilter);
      registration.setEnabled(false);
      return registration;
    }
}
```

This will add the filter to the chain.

**NOTE:** It might be that you need to add some additional configuration to inject the proper session context etc. into the custom filter. I'm not sure if the filter will have the correct ones injected automatically.

Comment: I injected AuthenticationManager into the class because it was needed to perform last line of attemptAuthentication method. `
    @Autowired
    public void setAuthenticationManager(@Lazy AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }`
I used Lazy to bypass cycle dependency between the class and securityConfig. 
The code runs, however session with empty pricipal_name is created. successfulAuthentication() method is triggered, userdetails fetched complete user entity, but the info is not persisted in db (principal_name).

Comment: You problably need to inject some additional services (like I mentioned in the note). Like the `SecurityContextRepository` and the `SessionAuthenticationStrategy`. For known filters this is configured automatically (or at least using things like `loginForm()`). But those are needed for proper operation.

Comment: Instead of `@Lazy` you also could define an `@Bean` method in your class and remove `@Component` from the class.

Comment: Oh yes, I've forgotten about injecting additional services. I've also used @Bean instead of ``@Lazy` as you suggested. It works and looks much cleaner now. I will add working code to my question, so that others with similar problem would find a solution. Anyway, big thanks for your solution and help. Really appreciate it!

Comment: I was also wondering what is the correct approach when I would like to login via rest api. Is it like this, using the filter or making a `loginForm()` and then sending a valid request with credentials to the endpoint connected with the loginForm. It means skipping spring boot template (for login page) and making own in React with sending right login request for automatically made `loginForm()`?

Comment: Either re-use the login endpoint by sending the parameters or use basic authentication and send the headers.

Comment: Okay, thanks once again